# Get right value from JSON

Tags: php

I have this JSON response with multiple values in the value field:

```
{
      "id": 2039,
      "key": "_cred_meta",
      "value": "a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:15:\"cred_product_id\";s:3:\"109\";s:12:\"cred_form_id\";i:55;s:12:\"cred_post_id\";i:383;}}"
    }
```

How can I get the last number 383 from this JSON in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is serialized PHP data inside of JSON.  First, unserialize the JSON, then unserialize the PHPS component.

Comment: I've never done this before. How can I handle this? After getting the value from the key my result looks like this now: a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:15:"cred_product_id";s:3:"109";s:12:"cred_form_id";i:55;s:12:"cred_post_id";i:383;}}

Comment: Fount a unserializer online: array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'cred_product_id' => '109',
    'cred_form_id' => 55,
    'cred_post_id' => 383,
  ),
) 
Now I have this and now I don't now how to get the id so far

Comment: If you assign the result of the unserializer to a variable, you can reach like $unserializedObject->cred_post_id , or you can simply add a "->cred_post_id" to unserializer statement.

Answer (score 1):

take a look a look here:

```
$value = "a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:15:\"cred_product_id\";s:3:\"109\";s:12:\"cred_form_id\";i:55;s:12:\"cred_post_id\";i:383;}}";
$res_array = unserialize( $value );
```

your result will be like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cred_product_id] => 109
            [cred_form_id] => 55
            [cred_post_id] => 383
        )

)
```

Hope this helps! :)